# Animate gradient bar chart - matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, animation

The following code animates a bar chart. I'm trying to apply a gradient and text labels to this animation though. The `autolabel()` function aims to add the text label and the `gradientbars()`functions aims to add the gradient. When applying here functions however, the animation just produces a still image.

I'm also hoping to adjust the gradient to a fixed point. Specifically, rather than applying the gradient to the extent of the individual bar height, I'm hoping to apply a max level of 6. Please see figure below regarding this.

I've commented out the specific functions below so the code works but applying them will produced the figure attached.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid(False)

data = np.random.randint(5, size=(10, 5))

x = ['A','B','C','D','E']
plt.ylim(0, 6)

rects = plt.bar(x, data[0])

def autolabel(rects):

    '''
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    '''
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05 * height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha = 'center', va = 'bottom')

def gradientbars(bars):

    grad = np.atleast_2d(np.linspace(0,5,256)).T

    cmap = 'Blues'
    
    ax = bars[0].axes
    lim = ax.get_xlim() + ax.get_ylim()

    for bar in bars:
    
        bar.set_zorder(1)
        bar.set_facecolor("none")
    
        x,y = bar.get_xy()
        w,h = bar.get_width(), bar.get_height()    
   
        ax.imshow(grad, extent = [x, x + w, y, y + h], aspect = "auto", zorder = 0, cmap = cmap)
    
    ax.axis(lim)

#autolabel(rects)

#gradientbars(rects)

def animate(i):

    for rect, yi in zip(rects, data[i]):
        rect.set_height(yi)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = len(data), interval = 100)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here? Why the figure is not an animation?

Comment: If you comment out the two functions the animation works. When applying the two function the animation doesn't work. I want the animation to work with the two functions

Comment: If you apply a the same limit of 6 to each gradient, they won't seem animated any more do they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do this:

```
def autolabel(rects):
    '''
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    '''
    ts = []
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        t = ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05 * height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha = 'center', va = 'bottom')
        ts.append(t)
    return ts

def gradientbars(bars, cmap, vmin, vmax):
    g = np.linspace(vmin,vmax,100)
    grad = np.vstack([g,g]).T
    xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    ymin,ymax = ax.get_ylim()
    ims = []
    for bar in bars:
        bar.set_facecolor('none')
        im = ax.imshow(grad, aspect="auto", zorder=0, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, extent=(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax))
        im.set_clip_path(bar)
        ims.append(im)
    return ims

Nbars=5
Nframes=10
vmin=0
vmax=6
cmap = 'Blues'
data = np.random.choice([0,1,2],size=(Nframes,Nbars))
data = data.cumsum(axis=1)
data[data>6] = 6
x=[chr(ord('A')+i) for i in range(Nbars)]
print(x)
print(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid(False)
plt.ylim(vmin, vmax)
rects = plt.bar(x,data[0])
labels = autolabel(rects)
imgs = gradientbars(rects, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

def animate(i):
    for rect,label,img,yi in zip(rects, labels, imgs, data[i]):
        rect.set_height(yi)
        label.set_text('%d'%int(yi))
        label.set_y(yi)
        img.set_clip_path(rect)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = len(data), interval = 500)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT**
Same with negative numbers

```
Nbars = 5
Nframes = 50
dt=50
cmap='coolwarm_r'
data = np.zeros(shape=(Nframes,Nbars))
for i in range(Nbars):
    d = np.sin(np.arange(0,Nframes*(dt*1e-3),dt*1e-3)*0.5*np.pi+np.random.uniform(low=-1., high=1.))
    data[:,i] = d
x = [chr(ord('A')+i) for i in range(Nbars)]
vmin = -1.
vmax = 1.


def gradientbars(bars, cmap, vmin, vmax):
    g = np.linspace(vmin,vmax,100)
    grad = np.vstack([g,g]).T
    xmin,xmax = ax.get_xlim()
    ymin,ymax = ax.get_ylim()
    ims = []
    for bar in bars:
        bar.set_facecolor('none')
        im = ax.imshow(grad, aspect="auto", zorder=0, cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, extent=(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax))
        im.set_clip_path(bar)
        ims.append(im)
    return ims

def autolabel(rects):
    '''
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    '''
    ts = []
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        va = 'bottom' if height>=0 else 'top'
        t = ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., height,
                f'{height:.2f}',
                ha ='center', va=va)
        ts.append(t)
    return ts


with plt.style.context('dark_background'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_ylim(vmin,vmax)

    rects = ax.bar(x=x, height=data[0,:])
    imgs = gradientbars(rects, cmap, vmin, vmax)
    labels = autolabel(rects)
    sns.despine(ax=ax, left=True, right=True, bottom=True, top=True)
    ax.set_yticks([])


def animate(i, data, rects, imgs, labels):
    for j,(rect,img,label) in enumerate(zip(rects,imgs,labels)):
        rect.set_height(data[i,j])
        img.set_clip_path(rect)
        label.set_y(data[i,j])
        label.set_va('bottom' if data[i,j]>=0 else 'top')
        label.set_text(f'{data[i,j]:.2f}')

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=Nframes, fargs=(data, rects, imgs, labels), interval=dt)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Diziet Asahi. I'm just trying to animate negative integer labels so it sits on top of the bar. I can get it going for a still image (see edit 2) but can't when the animation images begin.

Comment: I saw you've posted another question, but I added code that works for negative numbers as well